# preg_match PHP validating username

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

How to validate a username using php

My rules are:

Username can only contain letters, numbers and 1 underscore.

This is my current preg_match

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9][_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$_POST['uname'])
```

Comment: On at least two of your previous questions, you say "thanks", but didn't accept the answer. Go back over your other questions and, if an answer helped you, click the big check mark next to that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

Keep in mind that a character class of a single item is redundant. Write the atom solely instead. And `{1}` is another seriously redundant quantifier.

```
/[_]{1}/
```

is just the same as

```
/_/
```

---

Edit:

Based on the new constrains and in the helpful comment by chris, this seems to be a better regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/D
```

It matches usernames of at least two character, not ending or beginning with the optional underscore, and no newlines at the end.

Comment: Thanks :D

But I have another question, I also need that _ should not be first and last of the username

_myusername - not allowed
myusername_ - not allowed

Comment: @user1033600 what's the minimum number of characters allowed?

Comment: use the `D` flag unless you like usernames with a newline as the last character `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*_?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/D`

Comment: Sorry @chris I didn't know about this flag. I updated the answer —  thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: +1. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` does indeed work. However, a more efficient way of writing this would be: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$` This is _much_ more efficient in declaring a non-match when given longish invalid strings such as: `"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789#"`